# Can I add/install overhead kitchen cabinets without a wall?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, custom-cabinetry

### Setup

In my current kitchen, I have a semi-decent (yet always inadequate) amount of cabinet space. I would like to add some overhead cabinets over the peninsula. However, being a peninsula, there is no wall to which I could mount or anchor the cabinets.

### Restrictions

To make matters more interesting, the ceiling is vaulted, from roughly 8 feet at the lowest point (exterior wall) to 13 feet at the end of the peninsula.

As a further restriction, attic access to most of that portion of the attic is impossible due to the shape of the roof over that section of ceiling.

### Question

Do I have any (relatively simple) options as far as installation and mounting? I imagine I could create a wall on the back side of the peninsula, or find a way to mount/hang supports down from the roof joist. Could I mount them (using support beams) on top of the current cabinets? If so, I presume that could get in the way of replacing the countertops down the line (if not done correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a wall beside an island seems a major step backwards from current trends of open and airy interior architecture, which have been steadily embraced for decades.  The obvious solution would be to add a drop down wall, or even just suspend cabinets from the ceiling, like this:
[image].
(found [here](http://kitchenremodelingphotos.blogspot.com/2011_09_01_archive.html)).

One idea to help integrate that into the kitchen would be to add beams over the rest of the room:
[image]

To do this right requires cutting some holes into the ceiling, tying bracing into the ceiling joists, and then repairing the ceiling.  This is a medium sized job for a competent contractor, costing anywhere from $500 to $3000 depending on the scale and specifics of your house.  As a do-it-yourself, it is perhaps $50 in materials plus the cabinets and 20 to 60 hours of effort, most of which is drywall work to match the rest of the ceiling.

Comment: Thank @wallyk. I'd thought of #1, but I do like the way the general style of #2 looks as well, and can use those beams to drop cabinets or other styles of open storage down. Definitely food for thought after things settle down around here!